# Stuck Summing Cells with IF Statement Results in Them

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Helpful information:

```
 CELL: D2
 PURPOSE: INVOICE #
 FORMAT: PLAIN TEXT

 CELL: P2
 PURPOSE: COST OF PARTS PURCHASED
 FORMAT: ACCOUNTING WITH CURRENCY SIGN

 CELL: R2
 PURPOSE: QUANTITY OF PARTS PURCHASED
 FORMAT: NUMBER WITH NO DECIMALS

 CELL: Q2
 PURPOSE: QUANTITY OF PARTS PURCHASED
 FORMAT: NUMBER WITH NO DECIMAL PLACES
```

Hello,

I'm trying to multiply two cells using this formula =SUM(P2*Q2) in cell R2, and the results also going into cell R2.

```
 EXAMPLE: P2 ($2.00) * (x) Q2 (5) = R2 ($10.00)
```

Cell P2 contains an =IF formula to display $0.00 if the row is being used but the cell isn't, and a blank (or " ") if the row is not being used at all.

```
 FORMULA IN P2: =IF($D2>1,$Y$1," ")
```

Cell Q2 contains a formula to display 0 if the row is being used but the cell isn't, and a blank (or " ") if the row is not being used at all.

```
 FORMULA IN Q2: =IF($D2>1,$Y$1," ")
```

ISSUE:
Because the result of the =IF statements in cells P2 and Q2 are this: " ", the formula is returning a #VALUE! result. I'm guessing that the formula is looking for numbers, text and or nothing (literally), but is finding the result of the =IF statement, or " ".

This seems soooooo stinkin basic...

Anyway, any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new and I don't know how to do that. I feel like an idiot, This stuff would take me 10 seconds in Excel. But SHEETS is just that bit of difference that catches me off guard. I don't even know how to change my profile here!?! LOL So...

Comment: OK, I finally figured out how to change my profile. Now I'll work on uploading a worksheet for ya. Thx

Comment: Can you try returning "" instead of " "?

Comment: just copy-paste the url of the sheet here in a comment or in your question/post. also in sheet click on the green share button in top right corner and set up the share for "everyone with link".

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets formulas are able to return, literally, nothing. Instead of `" "` leave the third argument of IF empty.

```
=IF(condition,RESULT_TO_RETURN_IF_TRUE,)
```

Applying the above to the P2 formula

```
=IF($D2>1,$Y$1,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks player0, here is the WORKBOOK LINK: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CKJxJ3XWoSmTbCijgSAYkPpr2qvi_ZtZVYlKpWkk0q4/edit?usp=sharing

BTW, I told you I was stupid! I ended up using =IFERROR

Thanks,

DG